# Vertx Mock an async method with Handler<AsyncResult<>> argument

Tags: testing, mocking, mockito, vert.x

I have this data access interface:

```
public interface UserDao {

   void loadUsers(Handler<AsyncResult<List<User>>> handler);

}
```

And it's used in a service like this:

```
public class UserService {

  private UserDao userDao;

  public UserService(UserDao UserDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
  }

  public void getUsers(Future<List<User>> future) {
    userDao.loadUsers( ar ->{
      if (ar.succeeded()){
        List<User> users = ar.result();
        // process users
        future.complete(users);
      }else {
        // handle the error
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now my intention is to unit test my service and mock the data access layer. I want to return a fixed set of results every time getUsers method of UserDao class is called.

```
@Test
public void testGetUsers(TestContext context) {

  Async async = context.async();

  UserDao mockUserDao = Mockito.mock(UserDao.class);

  UserService userService = new UserService(mockUserDao);
  List<User> mockResult = Arrays.asList(new User(), new User());

  /* (?) How to make mockUserDao return mockResult through its Handler argument? */

  Future<List<User>> future = Future.future();
  userService.getUsers(future);
  future.setHandler(ar -> {
    assertEquals(2, ar.result().size());
    async.complete();
  });

  async.awaitSuccess();

}
```

How can I do that? It does not fit the normal Mockito pattern *when(serviceMock.method(any(Argument.class))).thenAnswer(new Result())* as *mockResult* is not returned from the method per say but through the handler.

Comment: Just a friendly comment, when it comes DAO layers, going down this route of sending in `Future` and things really become hard to understand and interpret when the code base starts growing, if you have really just started with your project my suggestion would be to use `Reactive Java`  for this stuff. If you would like I can definitely add code snippet describing things to you.

Answer (score 1):

Stub the function.

```
public class TestUserDao implements UserDao {
   void loadUsers(Handler<AsyncResult<List<User>>> handler) {
     handler.apply(mockResult)
   }
}

UserDao userDao = mock(UserDao.class, AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(new TestUserDao()));
verify(userDao).loadUsers(any());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check, if the loadUsers() has been invoked with a non-null handler, using an ArgumentCaptor. The ArgumentCaptor provides you access to the handler
to which you could pass a prepared result (either with a success or a failed result)

```
AsyncResult<List<User>> yourResult = ... //success or failure

ArgumentCaptor<Handler<AsyncResult<List<User>>>> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Handler.class);
Mockito.verify(userDao).loadUsers(captor.capture());
Handler<AsyncResult<List<User>>> handler = captor.getValue();
handler.handle(yourResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mock `Handler` also.

```
Handler mockedHandler = mock(Handler.class);
when(mockedHandler.result()).thenReturn(mockResult);
when(userDao.loadUsers(any(Handler.class))).thenReturn(mockedHandler);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because the handler is NOT returned by loadUsers method. That's the whole point of my question. See the last sentence in of my question.